# Change x,y from 1,1 to p,q using given rules

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a = p, b = q
In one cycle a can change to a = a + b or b = b + a
In any cycle either of two can be performed but not both.

Starting from a = 1, b = 1

Calculate no of iterations required to convert (x, y) from (1, 1) to (p,q) using the above mentioned rules.

Return not possible if cannot be done

Can anyone tell how to solve this problem.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Also, note that you will need to cite your sources of outside assistance.

Comment: Btw. if you always perform the operation on the smaller number you get the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Hint: go backwards. Having `p, q` what was the last operation?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment you can just go backwards. The larger element must be the one where the calculation was performed. So you could just do the reverse on the larger element and see if you end up with (1, 1). Or better subtract the smaller element directly as many times as needed from the larger one so that it becomes smaller than the other one:

```js
function steps(a, b) {
  let count = 0
  while (a != b) {
    console.log('(' + a + ', ' + b + ')')
    let t
    if (a > b) {
      t = a % b == 0 ? a / b - 1 : Math.floor(a / b)
      a -= t * b 
    } else {
      t = b % a == 0 ? b / a - 1 : Math.floor(b / a)
      b -= t * a
    }
    count += t
  }
  if (a == 1)
    return count
  return -1
}

console.log(steps(87, 13))
console.log(steps(23, 69))
```